# How do I restore a file from the recycle bin using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, recycle-bin

Moving files to the recycle bin and emptying the recycle bin are well documented, but how can a file be programmatically restored from the recycle bin?

Answer (score 5):

There seems not to be a solution in pure C#. You most likely have to resort to P/Invoke.
[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/recyclebin.aspx) presents a solution in C++ using the [SHFileOperation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHFileOperation) API.

Answer (score 2):

The only other reference to this beyond the previously mentioned link to [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/recyclebin.aspx) that I can see mentions this:

> Call `SHGetFolderLocation` passing `CSIDL_BITBUCKET`.
> Then you can manipulate that folder as usual.
> You'll have to create an interop for the `SHGetFolderLocation` function.

[`CSIDL_BITBUCKET` being the CSIDL ("constant special item ID list") value for the virtual Recycle Bin folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl). The quote is taken from [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/29_2003_11_0_0_117557/Restore-files-from-Recycle-Bin.htm), and will involve interop with the Windows shell. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180(VS.85).aspx) also mentions that this function has been deprecated in favour of another in Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will work to restore the files. Please make sure, STA Calls only supported for shell calls

```
     using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using Shell32; //Reference Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation on the COM tab.
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
    using System.Threading;


 private static void Restore(object param)
    {
        object[] args = (object[])param;
        string filename = (string)args[0];
        string filepath = (string)args[1];


        Shl = new Shell();
        Folder Recycler = Shl.NameSpace(10);
        var c = Recycler.Items().Count;

        var _recycler = Recycler.Items();
        for (int i = 0; i < _recycler.Count; i++)
        {
            FolderItem FI = _recycler.Item(i);
            string FileName = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 0);
            if (Path.GetExtension(FileName) == "") FileName += Path.GetExtension(FI.Path);
            //Necessary for systems with hidden file extensions.

            string FilePath = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 1);
            if (filepath == Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName))
            {
                DoVerb(FI, "ESTORE");
                break;                 
            }
        }        
    }

    private static bool DoVerb(FolderItem Item, string Verb)
    {
        foreach (FolderItemVerb FIVerb in Item.Verbs())
        {
            if (FIVerb.Name.ToUpper().Contains(Verb.ToUpper()))
            {
                FIVerb.DoIt();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```