# Restore from Recyclebin(C#)

Tags: c#, recycle-bin

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/05f1476f-a101-4766-847b-0bdf4f6ad397?prof=required).
Does the same code (JohnWein's answer) work in 9x,Me,2K,7 too?
If it doesn't please tell me what should i search for to do the same for 9x,Me,2k & 7?
Thanks

Comment: I see this, but I don't get what it has to do with anything. Perhaps you meant for it to be a link?

Comment: Sorry!
Here's the link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/05f1476f-a101-4766-847b-0bdf4f6ad397?prof=required

Comment: I'm sure I've asked about this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911391/

Answer (score 1):

[**How do I restore a file from the recycle bin using C#?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911391/how-do-i-restore-a-file-from-the-recycle-bin-using-c)

Have a look at this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/recyclebin.aspx). It uses **SHFileOperation** to perform operations in RecyclBin.

[image]

**EDIT :** To know how to use **SHFileOperation** in C# Please refer to [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell2.aspx) .This article continues to explore how to use the shell from C#.