# How to restore files from recycle bin

Tags: c#, winapi, file, restore, recycle-bin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restore a file from the recycle bin using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911391/how-do-i-restore-a-file-from-the-recycle-bin-using-c)

Someone knows how to restore files from recycle bin using C# with the Windows API?.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: Gosh, I did not see ... forgiveness.

Anyway, Thomas's response is correct and different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/05f1476f-a101-4766-847b-0bdf4f6ad397) can help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Shell32; //Reference Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation on the COM tab.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
namespace RecyclerCS
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Shell Shl;
    private const long ssfBITBUCKET = 10;
    private const int recycleNAME = 0;
    private const int recyclePATH = 1;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
      string S = "This is text in the file to be restored from the Recycle Bin.";
      string FileName = "C:\\Temp\\Text.txt";
      File.WriteAllText(FileName, S);
      Delete(FileName);
      MessageBox.Show(FileName + " has been moved to the Recycle Bin.");
      if (Restore(FileName))
        MessageBox.Show(FileName + " has been restored");
      else
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
      Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Shl);
    }
    private void Delete(string Item) {
      FileSystem.DeleteFile(Item, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
      //Gives the most control of dialogs.
    }
    private bool Restore(string Item) {
      Shl = new Shell();
      Folder Recycler = Shl.NameSpace(10);
      for (int i = 0; i < Recycler.Items().Count; i++) {
        FolderItem FI = Recycler.Items().Item(i);
        string FileName = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 0);
        if (Path.GetExtension(FileName) == "") FileName += Path.GetExtension(FI.Path);
        //Necessary for systems with hidden file extensions.
        string FilePath = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 1);
        if (Item == Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName)) {
          DoVerb(FI, "ESTORE");
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    private bool DoVerb(FolderItem Item, string Verb) {
      foreach (FolderItemVerb FIVerb in Item.Verbs()) {
        if (FIVerb.Name.ToUpper().Contains(Verb.ToUpper())) {
          FIVerb.DoIt();
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas: **Holy heaven, in the link you have given to me, is the solution, please excuse me.**

Comment: @Krähne: I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: "ESTORE" not applicable for non-English Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this project over here : [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell2.aspx)

### C# does Shell, Part 2 :

[image]