# What is the guid string that represents the file path?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I see the file in my trash bin has the path as:

```
C:\Recycle bin\{3x-for-example-guid-4x}\file.txt
```

I would like to know how to get the real path, the one before it is transfered to the trashbin.

Comment: @Sesame: don't put salutations or thank yous in your questions. See  [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You might want to alter your question title. In it you make the assumption that the GUID has anything to do with the original path of the deleted file.

Comment: Okay, I will say thanks face to face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer [in this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/05f1476f-a101-4766-847b-0bdf4f6ad397) for how to read out the path. Also see [How to restore files from recycle bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025311/how-to-restore-files-from-recycle-bin)

The original link refers to a C++ article: [How to programmatically use the Recycle Bin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/recyclebin.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Chen has recently blogged about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/30/10202076.aspx).  The article uses COM and C++ to query information about an object in the recycle bin, including the original path - which I assume is what you mean by "real path".

Comment: Thanks, Christian K, I visited his site before and didn't pay attention he added it in there so fast.=)