# How can one access all the files/directories in the user's recycle bin in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, recycle-bin

---

**NOTE:  To be clear, I do not want to empty the recycle bin as answered in other questions.**

---

Using answers from other questions on both Stack Overflow and Super User I have discovered the way to get the location of one's recycle bin in C# is:

`@"C:\$Recycle.Bin\" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString()`

However, when I run the following code I am getting different files to what is actually in my recycle bin:

```
string location = @"C:\$Recycle.Bin\" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(location))
{
    Console.Writeline(file);
}
```

How can I correctly get all the files in my recycling bin? My needs are to access when the files were last used and to possibly then restore them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's not as straight forward as initially thought because the Recycle Bin doesn't have a physical location, it's a virtual folder. To get a list of all files in the Recycle Bin and make this work you need to add a reference to shell32.dll (located in %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(0x000a);

    foreach (FolderItem2 item in folder.Items())
        Console.WriteLine("FileName:{0}", item.Name);

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(shell);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

REF: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/161500-play-with-recycle-bin-in-code/

To get the LastModified Property of the files you can see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660616/

Also note there's a Recycle Bin for each HDD so you will have to check all drives.

To restore files here is the solution in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6025331/495455

Comment: Wow, thank you. Your code works perfectly and I'll test the restoring files stuff now. I'm assuming after I restore it I can keep track of it's now restored location?

Comment: Yes its *new* restored filepath will be a property on the `FolderItem` object. You can save this to a database or whatever to keep track of files that have been deleted but you've detected should not have been. Just a FYI not sure what you plan on doing when users Empty the recycle bin or if they use a program to destroy evidence that the file ever existed, here is a list: https://www.howtogeek.com/72130/learn-how-to-securely-delete-files-in-windows/

Comment: I'm struggling slightly because in the example they're using the location of the file from *before* it was recycled to restore it. I only have it's location in the recycle bin

Comment: To get the **original location** it should be `objFolder.GetDetailsOf(item, indexes[39])`

Comment: Thanks again, that's just what I needed!

Comment: Add [STAThread()] above the main method to get away with the exception