# get the date when the file was sent to recycle bin

Tags: c#, shell32, recycle-bin

Is there any call which will get the date when the file was sent to recycle bin.

Items object in `Shell32` gives the `lastmodified` date but not when it is sent to recycle bin.

I want to be able to restore files deleted on a particular date.

Comment: I think that when enumerating files in the recycle bin, the last-modified time is also the deletion time. See [Automatically deleting old files from recycling bin while keeping the new ones?](http://superuser.com/q/434626/94017) on Super User.

Comment: The answers here reference some articles that might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911391/how-do-i-restore-a-file-from-the-recycle-bin-using-c?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - as usual it is very simple when you know how. I was thinking this would be a property of the file - but it is not - it is a property of the recycle bin.

So once a link to the recycle bin has been got:

```
var Shl = new Shell();
Folder Recycler = Shl.NameSpace(10); 
FI = Recycler.Items().Item(0);   
string FileName = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 0); 
string FilePath = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 1); 
string RecyleDate = Recycler.GetDetailsOf(FI, 2);
```

The lastmodified date is a separate property that refers solely to the deleted file.