# How do I get the "Deleted Date" of files in the Windows Recycle Bin

Tags: vb.net

Thanks to Ravindra Bagale I now have access to the Recycle bin (Although why it's not a "Special Folder" Microsoft only knows!), but I was to have access to the date that the item arrived in the recycle bin. It's displayed in the Details view but I cannot get at it...

I've tried the usual places (creating date, modified date etc.) of both the item in the recycle bin and the actual file in the recycle bin...

Has anyone else achieved this?

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871456/get-the-date-when-the-file-was-sent-to-recycle-bin

Comment: This article on working with the Windows recycle bin with C# may help you:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/164491-working-with-the-windows-recycle-bin-with-c%23/

Comment: For others, here is previous question with answer on accessing the recycle bin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208338/accessing-the-recycle-bin.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I looked at the c# article but it does not mention deleted date nor 'GetDetailsOf' - unless I missed it.

Now, I have the date but it's full of Non-ascii characters. so needs further processing - which seems to be a good example of poor standards!

Comment: @Andrew', was the link Mohamed provided of help?  As for the date format, could you provide the source code you are using to retrieve the date along with an example dump of what it looks like?

Comment: The original poster didn't bother to answer Richard's question about whether Mohamed's link helped. I have confirmed that that link does indeed provide a correct method to obtain the date deleted, as well as the original location of the file.